# Manipulating Series To Find Maximum Interval Of Convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, geometric-series

Original Problem: Use the formula for the sum of a geometric series to find a power series that converges to expressions. For what values of y does the series converge?

$$8\over 4+y$$

Formula for the sum of a geometric series are written in the form $$a\over1-r$$ where a is the first term and r is the common ratio.

I did various approaches to this problem and got different interval of convergence, however, I wanted to find the maximum interval of convergence, so I tried this:

$$\lim_{b \to \infty } {{1\over b}\over {1\over b}}{8\over4+y}$$

$$\lim_{b \to \infty } {{8\over b} \over {{4+y}\over b}}$$

From this, I added a fancy 0 to the denominator, and then I rewrote the expression in terms of the sum of a geometric series.

$$\lim_{b \to \infty } {{8\over b} \over 1-1+ {{4+y}\over b}}$$

$$\lim_{b \to \infty } {{8\over b} \over 1-(1- {{4+y}\over b})}$$

Last, I transform the expression into the Riemann sums, so I could use the Ratio Test to find the interval of convergence (1*).

$$\lim_{b \to \infty } \sum_{n=0}^\infty {8 \over b} \left( {1- {{4+y}\over b}} \right)^n$$

Ratio Test:
$$\lim_{b \to \infty }\lim_{n \to \infty } \left\lvert{{{8 \over b}({1- {{4+y}\over b}})^{n+1}}\over{{{8 \over b}({1- {{4+y}\over b}})^n}}} \right\rvert < 1 $$

This simplifies to:

$$\lim_{b \to \infty } \left(-1 < 1-{{4+y}\over b} < 1\right) $$

$$\lim_{b \to \infty} (2b-4 > y > -4) $$

Which I then simplify to:

$$\infty > y > -4 $$

My main question here, am I able to do this to find an interval of convergence? My concern is that when I pick a value for y that was in my interval and put the Riemann sum (at 1*) into my calculator, TI-Nspire CX, it wasn't able to solve and instead it spit it right back. My second question was now that I have this huge interval of convergence because my calculator can't calculate the sum, can I just use the original expression $8 / (4+y)$ to evaluate a sum given a chosen y that's in the interval?

Comment: Why did you introduce $\lim_{b\to\infty}$?

Comment: because I wanted to see if I can increase the interval of convergence.

Comment: The interval of convergence is whatever it is, nothing you do can "increase" it

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
\frac{8}{4+y} &=
\frac{8}{4+y}\cdot 
\frac{\frac{1}{4}}{\frac{1}{4}}\\[4pt]
&=\frac{2}{1+\frac{y}{4}}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{2}{1-\left(-\frac{y}{4}\right)}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

which can be expressed as a geometric series with $$a=2,\;r = -\frac{y}{4}$$
hence converges if and only if $\large{\left|-\frac{y}{4}\right|<1}$, so the interval of convergence is $-4 < y < 4$.

But in your comments, you asked whether the interval for $y$ can be enlarged by shifting the center.

Let's say you shift the center to $y=1$. Thus

\begin{align*}
\frac{8}{4+y} &=
\frac{8}{5+(y-1)}\\[4pt]
&=\frac{8}{5+(y-1)}\\[4pt]
&=\frac{8}{5+(y-1)}\cdot \frac{\frac{1}{5}}{\frac{1}{5}}\\[4pt]
&=\frac{\frac{8}{5}}{1+\frac{y-1}{5}}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{\frac{8}{5}}{1-\left(-\frac{y-1}{5}\right)}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

which can be expressed as a geometric series with $$a=\frac{8}{5},\;r = -\frac{y-1}{5}$$
hence converges if and only if $\large{\left|-\frac{y-1}{5}\right|<1}$, so the interval of convergence is $-4 < y < 6$.

In general, if you shift the center to $y=c$, where $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and $c \ne -4$, the new radius of convergence will be $|4+c|$, and the interval of convergence for $y$ will the open interval centered at $y=c$, with one endpoint at $-4$.

So yes, the interval of convergence for $y$ can be made larger by centering the series further away from $-4$, but note, regardless of the choice of center, the interval of convergence will still be bounded.

Comment: Yes I have done that approach, and it gives me the interval of 4 > y > -4. However, I was trying to find a greater interval of convergence.

Comment: Centered at $y=0$, you certainly can't enlarge the interval $(-4,4)$.

Comment: I agree, however, what if I move the center. For instance, I have tried rewriting the expression as $$ 8 \over 1-(-3-y) $$ which gave me an interval of (-4, -2).

Comment: So in my above example, I feel I have moved the center to create a larger interval.

Comment: That's a smaller interval.

Comment: I know it is, I'm making the point that the interval can change size depending on the approach.

Comment: But yes, if you shift the center to $y=c$, where $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and $c \ne -4$, then the new radius of convergence will be $|c+4|$, so can be made arbitrarily large.